# Java version compatible

Tags: java, version

I have a server with java code running and need to setup the same environment on another server to run the code

Now when I try to run my program I get this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.(java.io.InputStream)'

but on the first machine working fine and getting the result

I run java -v on first machine and get this result

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.1.002)
SAP Java Server VM (build 8.1.002 25.11-b13, Dec 16 2014 04:44:15 - 81_REL - optU - windows x86 - 6 - bas2:230506 (mixed mode))

but I can't find the same environment to install on the other server and make my program work

Comment: Are you asking where to find that specific version of the JRE? If so please notice that questions asking us to recommend **or find** a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: What does it mean I can't find the same environment? You should install the same JRE on the other server for compatibility. The advice I can give you is to use tools like Docker to make your apps portable to different environments, thus saving a lot of time for the migration.

Comment: My problem is that the program I have doesn't work on other machine and can't find the same environment as the first one, so don't know if this is a specific version of java or something like this

Comment: @DaniloGiovannico Once I get the right environment will use docker but I wasn't who initialized the application :D

Comment: Even if you could find that specific JDK, you shouldn't be using it: it's been built in December 2014. You really don't want to be running something that ancient in production. You should switch *at least* to the most recent Java 8 version accessible to you, but ideally to a more recent JDK (which might require fixing the underlying issue).